# How to perform search for protein or nucleotide search in uspto

Tags: search

I had been trying to search for patents on proteins using amino acid sequence or nucleoside sequence for presence of patents but i am unable to find the relevant patents for the same.

Please help me how could i perform search in USPTO or any other relevant databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't vouch for its effectiveness since I've never used it, but [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/) has [patent sequence search facility](https://www.lens.org/lens/bio). [This page](https://www.lens.org/lens/bio/patseqfinder) is specifically for searching sequences. I do use The Lens for regular patent searching and think it works well and generally better than Google Patents.

Comment: Does any patent office support such search like USPTO or ESPACENET ?

Comment: @RishiM Although I worked in molecular diagnostics for years, I'm an engineer and never did sequence searching myself. So I can't answer your question. Certainly The Lens does searching in many jurisdictions worldwide.